# Does Swift have an implicit Object Initializer, like in C#?

Tags: swift

In C#, we have Object Initializers, like so:

```
    Person obj = new Person
    {
        FirstName = "Craig",
        LastName = "Playstead",
    };
```

Does Swift have this?

As an example, I have this code:

```
var config = IndicatesConfig()
config.name = NSLocalizedString(Localizable.FOLDERS, comment: "").uppercaseString
config.style = .DetailHeader
return config
```

But would like to do something along the lines of:

```
var config = IndicatesConfig() {
    name = NSLocalizedString(Localizable.FOLDERS, comment: "").uppercaseString
    style = .DetailHeader
}
```

Thank you!

edit:

I'm not referencing to the explicit definition of class initialisers. Please bear in mind the syntax shown in the C# example.

Comment: [The Swift Programming Language Initialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html)

Comment: And you didn't find the answer in the Swift books by Apple? Really?

Comment: Why the down vote? No, I didn't. I have it open right here. Maybe I wasn't clear enough. I was not referencing to the definition of class initialisers.

Comment: The reason C# has this syntax is that it doesn't have the superior features that Swift does: extension initializers and named tuples. Without named tuples, the syntax makes sense, for C#'s anonymous types (which have the overhead of having to be objects). As it stands, if you do what you're doing, once, you get no benefit from the object initializer. If you do it twice, then you should make your own extension initializer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not as such. If you create a custom `struct`, Swift will, under certain conditions, create a [default memberwise initializer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-XID_318) that is close to what you're looking for. But otherwise, I don't think there's even a way to implement such a feature, since Swift lacks anything like a `with` keyword that would get you into the new instance's scope.

*Update:* this is as close as I can get, by defining a custom operator:

```
infix operator <| { }

func <|<T>(decl: @autoclosure () -> T, f: T -> () ) -> T {
    let obj = decl()
    f(obj)
    return obj
}

let label = UILabel() <| {
    $0.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 300, height: 25)
    $0.text = "Hello"
    $0.enabled = false
}

println(label)
// <UILabel: 0x7fb46240b210; frame = (10 10; 300 25); text = 'Hello'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7fb46240c2b0>>
```

Comment: If you're defining your own `with` equivalent and don't like all that `$0`, you can also use the short closure-parameter-naming syntax: e.g. `let label = UILabel() <| { v in v.frame = ...; v.text = ...; v.enabled = ... }`

Comment: This is great. `f` can be annotated with `@noescape` in Swift 1.2. But why do you make `decl` a function rather than just a `T`?

Comment: in Swift2.2 function prototype should change to `func <|<T>(@autoclosure decl: () -> ...`

Comment: Do you have an example of `struct` default memberwise initalizers?

Answer (score 7):

Swift doesn't have such feature.

You can implement similar interface using closure, but...

```
class MyClass {
    var name = ""
    var style = 0
    init(initializer:((MyClass)->Void)? = nil) {
        initializer?(self)
    }
}

let a = MyClass2() {
    $0.name = "foo"
    $0.style = 2
}
```

There is no implicit `self` here, instead, you have to use implicit closure parameter `$0`.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly I'm not understanding, but Swift does have initializers. By default, the initializer does not take any parameters, but you can always add additional initializers that take any number of parameters...

```
class MyClass {
  var _name: String
  var _style: Int = 0

  init() {
    _name = ""
  }
  init(_ name : String) {
    _name = name
  }
}
```

If you want to ADD an initializer, you can write an extension

```
extension MyClass {
  convenience init(_ name: String, style: Int) {
    self.init(name)
    _style = style
  }
}
```

Then you can instantiate this object using any of the following:

```
var a = MyClass()
var b = MyClass("Billy")
var c = MyClass("Jimmy", 5)
```

Comment: Aside from your underscores, this is the appropriate solution.

Comment: This is not what OP is talking about. He's talking about an initializer that you don't have to manually write and can optionally provide values for

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but I still stumbled across this in searching for an answer. So far I have learned that you can use a convenience constructor and pass in a closure to accomplish something close. Hope this helps anyone looking.

```
extension Person {

    public convenience init(_ closure: (Person) -> ()) {
        self.init()
        closure(self)
    }
    public convenience init(city: String, _ closure: (Person) -> ()) {
        self.city = city
        self.init()
        closure(self)
    }
}

// usage
var person = Person() { (p: Person)
    p.FirstName = "Craig"
    p.LastName = "Playstead"
})

var person = Person(city: "Phoenix") { (p: Person)
    p.FirstName = "Craig"
    p.LastName = "Playstead"
})
```